# Rails Action Cable: How can I access instance variables within ApplicationCable::Channel Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I would like to create chatrooms per product page so that uses can chat about the product while they are isolated from other products' discussions.

For this purpose; I was planning to use @product instance varialbe while defining the subscriptions however it seems; instance variables are not accessible within Action Cable

**"app/channels/product_channel.rb"**

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel_product_#{@product.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end
end
```

How can I access instance variables within channel module??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't access the instance variable while defining the subscriptions. But you can pass product_id as a parameter, then you subscribe to the ProductChannel. 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#subscriber

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "ProductChannel", product_id: your_product_id }
```

And on your channel, you can access to "product_id" like:

```
def subscribed
  stream_from "product_channel_#{params[:product_id]}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable in your `subscribed` method. Think of the `subscribed` method as an initializer in the context of your channel.

An example [exists within the ActionCable codebase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb#L44) itself. In your case, this can be achieved like  so

```rb
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    stream_from "room_channel_product_#{@product.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end

  def foo
    @product.do_stuff
  end
end
```